# Бан в чате за сообщения без оскорблений

Tags: поддержка, модерация, бан

Насколько я понимаю, сегодня модератором @PashaPash были удалены следующие три моих сообщения в чате с помощью тревоги, что приводило к банам (так работают модераторские тревоги).

1. Из обсуждения критериев модераторов:

   > Squidward: @NicolasChabanovsky Есть критерии, которые не выясняются через вопросы "что бы вы сделали"... Отвечая на вопрос про ключевые личные качества модератора, я поставил первым пунктом **хладнокровие** не просто так. Насколько легко можно вывести модератора из себя — это очень важный фактор. Я флегматичен: меня практически нереально вывести из себя, но если вывести, то сложно остановить. Вас и двух из трёх модераторов я никогда не видел во взъерошенном виде. Это — огромное достоинство для модератора.

   Я считаю, что указать человеку на взволнованность, возбудимость (см. [взъерошенность](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8A%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) (3)) — это не оскорбление. Как хладнокровие, так и возбудимость — нейтральные характеристики поведения, и могут быть как положительными, так и отрицательными в разных ситуациях.
2. Реакция на многочисленные сообщения @PashaPash в мой адрес в чате, в том числе когда я был забанен и не мог парировать:

   > Squidward: @NicolasChabanovsky Я-то не буду ссориться, а вот читать сотни однообразных нелестных комментариев в свой адрес от одного юзера несколько надоедает. Я рассчитываю на сознательность других участников, что они не будут вестись на его провокации в мой адрес и строить обо мне превратное мнение с третьих слов, но всё-таки всему есть мера.

   Я считаю, что я могу попросить участника, независимо от его ранга, воздержаться от агрессивных сообщений, направленных лично мне.
3. Описание ситуации другому участнику, который упомянул неравноправность в споре при разных рангах:

   > Squidward: Меня сегодня уже дважды забанили в чате. Удалено два сообщения, в которых я не вижу оскорблений. Объяснений не последовало. Вот такой вот спор с модераторами.

   Обсуждать в нейтральном тоне действия модераторов — допустимо.

При этом сам модератор писал следующие сообщения:

1. > PashaPash: @Squidward буду рад, когда вашу кандидатуру снимут. троллям не место в модераторах

   Я расцениваю это как оскорбление.
2. > PashaPash: @FoggyFinder мне не нравится троллинг под прикрытием "я просто так всех проверяю"

   Многократное повторение оценочного мнения (троллинг), в этот раз на базе моего сообщения:

   > Squidward: Я написал некоторое количество комментариев с критикой к речам номинантов. То, как они отреагировали на них, дало мне не меньше информации, чем собственно ответы (большинство ответов были хорошими, кстати). И то, какие комментарии я получил в свой адрес под своими ответами на вопросы номинантам, тоже сказало мне, что я ошибся в одном голосе на прошлых выборах. Ну что ж, поздно пить Боржоми.

   Речь идёт про мои комментарии к речам номинантов, в которых я выразил критику:

   1. > У вас распределение между голосами "+" и "–" за вопросы и ответы 8410 / 266. Вы избегаете минусования? Почему? Цена минусования вопросов была обнулена, потому что администрация сайта считает адекватные оценки, отражающие качество контента, важными для посетителей. Вы считаете иначе?
   2. > За полтора года присутствия на сайте вы практически не участвовали в модерации сайта: у вас очень мало постов на Мете, правок, тревог и проверок — несмотря на высокую репутацию и доступ ко множеству модераторских инструментов. Вы считаете, что после избрания модератором вы будете более активны? Почему? Учитывая модерирование нескольких сайтов, вы уверены, что вам хватит времени?
   3. > Вы не слишком активны на Мете: у вас только 4 ответа, не относящихся к выборам. Вам это неинтересно?

   Как мне кажется, эти сообщения не могут считаться троллингом. Более того, абсолютно аналогичные сообщения про недостаток активности писали другие участники другим кандидатам.
3. Ну и дальше опять обвинения в троллинге и фантазии на тему моих мотивов:

   > PashaPash: мне не нравится троллинг под прикрытием "я просто так всех проверяю"
   >
   > PashaPash: от любого участника. кто ж виноват, что тут таким занимается только один человек
   >
   > PashaPash: причем если реакции нет - то считается что это был не троллинг, а "конструктивная критика". а если есть - значит "о, как я красиво вас проверил на моральную устойчивость"

   И так далее и тому подобное.

Последняя попытка выяснить причину удалений и банов закончилась очередным баном, правда мне процитировали сообщение:

> PashaPash: @Squidward очень настойчиво советую вам завязать с косвенными обвинениями. комнату уже замораживали, и сразу же после прошлой заморозки вы выкатили сообщение с выпадами в мою сторону. его также снесли. считайте что это официальное предупреждение

Я решительно не понимаю, какое правило я нарушил. Обвинение модератора в отсутствии хладнокровия? Обвинение модератора в том, что он действительно сделал (забанил меня)? Я не улавливаю мысль.

Я пытался отшучиваться ("Мне до Казани доносится эхо лязга ваших зубов. :-D Ну хватит бояться, не смогу я победить на этих выборах! :-D"), пытался призвать к порядку, пытался позвать других модераторов, всё тщетно.

На данный момент я не имею права обсуждать выборы, кандидатов, модерацию, собственные баны — я сразу улетаю в бан. При этом модератор, который меня банит, продолжает писать сообщения в одностороннем порядке и делать вид, что так и должно быть.

Я не знаю, что делать. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Я тут новенький, не в курсе местных войн, но, по моему, выбирать модераторов (депутатов, президентов, etc) нужно как раз задавая неудобные вопросы.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n Согласен, дебаты очень важны для выборов. Причём в каких-нибудь Штатах, где дебаты занимают значительную часть медиа-пространства перед выборами и имеют внушительную историю, а не являются формальным огрызком, как в России — там и статистику использованных предлогов считают, и формулу движения бровей кандидатов высчитывают, то есть активно занимаются анализом "как" кандидат отвечал, а не только "что". Анализ поведения окружающих — вообще неотъемлемый аспект социальной жизни человека.

Comment: я бы не стал равняться на Штаты или Россию и вообще всячески против переноса политики в интернет или по крайней мере такие уважаемые ресурсы. Но всё же считаю, что даже технически грамотный, но психованный модератор не нужен, и в ваших вопросах и комментариях я не увидел ничего противоправного. Хороший модератор, к тому же, должен уметь распознать троллинг и грамотно парировать доступными ему инструментами.

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n вам и не нужно быть в курсе войн. Весь контекст конфликта в конце концов должен оказаться в вопросе и ответах, чтобы из них можно было делать выводы и в дальнейшем (а не только сейчас). Если считаете, что чего-то не хватает для полного понимания конфликта, спросите. Если вроде всё на месте -- не заморачивайтесь :)

Comment: @D-side вообще странно видеть конфликты на ресурсе, который создавался для помощи друг другу :) Хотя предсказуемо, что кому-то всегда хочется власти там, где есть над кем властвовать. Make love, not war.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью с вами согласен. Дебаты важны для выборов. Более того, дебаты не должны быть односторонними. Именно поэтому я не понимаю, почему у вас мой достаточно простой вопрос

> Вы не участвуете в просмотре очередей с июля. Зачем вам дополнительные инструменты, если вы не пользуетесь теми, что уже доступны? Т.е. да, вы разгребаете очереди набегами - но какой смысл идти в модераторы, если модерированием вы будете заниматься раз в три месяца

привел к настолько острой реакции с вашей стороны. Ведь сами вы задали аналогичный вопрос другому кандидату.

---

Ваш бан в чате не имеет никакого отношения к конструктивным замечаниям под кандидатурами других участников.

Лично я считаю сомнительным заморозку комнаты за то, что в ней обсуждалась активность кандидатово в очередях проверок и проблема искажения данных при сведении их к баллам кандидатов. На мой взгляд, это достаточно серъезная проблема, особенно для текущих выборов. Но, тем не менее, как модератор - я вынужден был поддержать эту заморозку. Именно поэтому я поставил две последних тревоги из трех обсуждаемых.

*К сожалению, первое из удаленных сообщений удалил не я*, поэтому выводы в вашем сообщении выше в значительной мере искажены.
Жаль, что вы приняли решение другого модератора как агрессию в вашем отношении лично с моей стороны.

Тем не менее, прошу вас заметить, что это сообщение (как и оставшиеся два удаленных мной) вы оставили *непосредственно после того, как другой модератор настойчиво и однозначно попросил вас не продолжать*.

Два моих флага было поставлено на сообщения, в которых вы пытались продолжить обсуждение моего, якобы, предвзятого отношения к вам. Судя по всему, это было вызвано неверным предположением, о том, что я вас, якобы, забанил. После заморозки комнаты Николасом из-за именно такого обсуждения. Я, как модератор, вынужден было это обсуждение прекратить (хотя мне очень хотелось его продолжить), сопроводив это достаточно нейтральным комментарием.

> Реакция на многочисленные сообщения в мой адрес в чате, в том числе когда я был забанен и не мог парировать

Значительная часть этих сообщений касалась проблемы бана участников с высокой репутацией в общем. [Я прямо написал об этом в чате лично вам. И даже извинился за сложившееся впечатление](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40516588#40516588). Причем написал вам об этом до постановки тревог лично мной. Проблема бана высокоуровневых участников достаточно актуальна, и даже вынесена в вопросы для модераторов. Минимум два участника (исключая вас) попали под бан за такое поведение, с небольшой разницей в концовке. Для меня, как для действующего модератора, это проблема тем более актуальна, и я считаю допустимым обсуждать ее с другими участниками, без упоминания конкретных личностей. Если вы против - просто не участвуйте в обсуждении. Но не стоит принимать это обсуждение полностью на свой счет.

Еще раз приношу свои извинения, если вы сочли обсуждение бана высокореповых участников направленным лично против вас.

Если обсуждение достаточно неприятного и неконструктивного поведения участника вызывает у вас ассоциации лично с вами - это достаточно серьезный повод задуматься, хороший ли из вас выйдет модератор.

---

Нудное описание моих флагов:

Вот ваше первое сообщение, на которое я поставил тревогу:

> не буду ссориться, а вот читать сотни однообразных нелестных комментариев в свой адрес от одного юзера несколько надоедает. Я рассчитываю на сознательность других участников, что они не будут вестись на его провокации в мой адрес и строить обо мне превратное мнение с третьих слов, но всё-таки всему есть мера.

Вы оставили его сразу же после, как комната была была разморожена. И *после* моего *достаточно однозначного комментария*, что я обсуждаю не ваше поведение, а проблему бана в целом. Тревога сопровождалась достаточно детальным объяснением причины ее постановки:

> очень настойчиво советую вам завязать с косвенными обвинениями. комнату уже замораживали, и сразу же после прошлой заморозки вы выкатили сообщение с выпадами в мою сторону. его также снесли. *считайте что это официальное предупреждение*.

Согласен, причина была сформулирована достаточно эмоционально. Но тем не менее - вас два модератора прямо попросило не продолжать.

Аналогично, вторую тревогу я поставил на сообщение:

> Меня сегодня уже дважды забанили в чате. Удалено два сообщения, в которых я не вижу оскорблений. Объяснений не последовало. Вот такой вот спор с модераторами.

Мне показались достаточно неконструктивным ваши попытки представить себя в виде жертвы и вернуться к обсуждению угнетения модератором лично вас. О причинах причинах такого решения я также прямо написал в чате

> я не продолжаю дискуссию. я пресек попытки ее продолжить (в любом виде).

Не стоит продолжать спор, после того, как два модератора прямо попросили вас перестать.

Answer (score 0):

#### Подобное поведение должно быть недопустимо. Особенно со стороны модератора.

1. В указанных Squidward сообщениях не содержится ничего оскорбительного (как впрочем и приведенные сообщения PashaPash, боле-менее в рамках).
2. Сообщения Squidward были адресованы другому человеку (модератору), который сам мог принять необходимые действия, если бы посчитал их оскорбительными.
3. Squidward это активный кандидат. Налицо использование административного ресурса для затыкания рта со стороны модератора.

Раз уж на то пошло, то это PashaPash должен был бы создавать тему о неприличном поведении столь значимого кандидата, с вынесением на обсуждение вопроса о его снятии с выборов.

*Прошу поправить, если я в чем-то не прав*

---

Я не совсем понимаю, как работает система тревог и банов. Травля Squidward это единоличное решение PashaPash или все же коллегиальное решение?

Comment: Первый бан в чате был не от меня, и не по моей тревоге. Два вторых бана - от меня (точнее, по моей тревоге на сообщения Squidward, в  продолжал обвинять меня "в травле" после того, как тема была явно и однозначно объявлена оффтопом и привела к заморозке комнаты)

Comment: @PashaPash Для полноты картины, можно вас попросить привести цитирование и пояснения двум банам в вашем ответе?

Comment: привел. оба моих флага были поставлены в ответ на попытку продолжить обсуждение после того, как участника попросили перестать

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо. +1